# Unable to create a Connected App: "The application name has been used before" even when it has not

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, connected-apps

I managed to add a connected app in a sandbox instance but when I try to add one in the production instance, I receive this error.

> The application name [name] / [API name] has been used before. Use a new unique name for your application.

This happens no matter what name or API name I try.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Setup > Create > Apps > Connected Apps > New
2. Fill out the connected app name, API name, contact email.
3. I used OAuth settings (but tried with others and got the same problem)
4. Save

Here's [a post in their support forum of the same issue](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008oEdIAI) (dating back to June 2013) and there are no solutions. Some potential help has been provided but the article linked to does not work any more.

I just need to make a connected app so that I can get an API key to use the REST API with. If there is a different way of doing this, that would also be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a similar known issue from 7 days ago. [Connected App partial copy to sandboxes, App is available in sandbox (not visible in UI)](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SzR4AAK). However, it does seem distinct from your issue.

Comment: Thanks. It's similar but still distinct. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd start with raising a support case. Other than that, a completely random name and API name?

Comment: I raised a support case and they just closed it directing me to the developer forums (I posted in the linked thread above). I've tried completely random names (50 char alphanumeric) and that doesn't help sadly.

Comment: Personally I think it is crazy that we can't raise a platform bug directly with Salesforce support and need to wait for them to find it in the forums. How are they going to inspect the Org to get the required details? </rant> :) Personally, I think I'd start a new support forum post and link back to the previous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by an issue on Salesforce's side. I was told that they used a "special developer tool" (how vague...) to fix it. If you encounter this problem, you will have to contact their support team to get it sorted.

Unfortunately, we had to purchase Premier Support for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. I was entering a single word as Connected App Name. and it showed Invalid Module name error.
What fixed it was i entered name as "Word1"(Space)""Word2" and this fixed it for me. "Woo Integration" i used this name to fix it.