# OAuth Username-Password Flow - Inconsistent login failure

Tags: integration, oauth2, connected-apps

Noticing this behavior in my Full Sandbox after refreshing it. Whenever a third party application is trying to loggin using OAuth Username-password flow it gets the below error 3 out of 5 times. But not everytime. Which means the credentials and code are correct otherwise it wont log me in at all times. Whenever there is a failure, I don't see any logs on the user record. On success I see a successful entry in the login history. The same happens when I try to login through cUrl or any other client.

> { "error_description": "expired access/refresh token", "error":
>   "invalid_grant" }

Could this be due to the Sandbox refresh or some sort of performance issue? Not sure what I can do about this, and how to handle it.

Also another thing I noticed is that when refreshing a sandbox the "Connected Apps" (Create->Apps->Connected Apps section) don't get copied. However the Production consumer key and consumer secret seem to work somehow for that app in the Sandbox. That is confusing.

[image]

Comment: Adding to the above, there were no login denied entries as well when proceeding with the above sequence! We are experiencing this in cs14 instance but that box doesn't have any issues as per Trust site! Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be related to your problem. See more information at this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45890/unable-to-create-a-connected-app-the-application-name-has-been-used-before-ev). Basically Salesforce has a bug in terms of pulling down the connected app from live when you do a refresh. It might explain the second problem you have experienced and it might solve the first problem with the failure to log in. Maybe creating a different connected app with a different name in the sandbox and then change the login details and the name of the connected app in your third party app. See if it logs in every time, hope it helps

Comment: Yes. Seems to be a Salesforce issue. Also the erratic behavior seems to have corrected itself on its own today.